# Is a battery management system necessary for wearables?

Tags: lithium-ion, lithium-polymer, wireless-charging

My team and I are working on developing a wearable device (like a heart rate monitor with IP68 dust/waterproofing) and we're utilising wireless charging for our 3.7V 350mAh non-removable battery.

We'll be using TI's [BQ51050B](http://www.ti.com/product/bq51050B) IC and whilst it performs the roles of wireless receiver and battery charger in one IC, I noted that it does not perform the full suite of voltage, current and temperature protections that a good battery management system (like the [BQ77905](http://www.ti.com/product/BQ77905)) does.

I have reviewed a few different safety standards including IEC, UL and CE and they all discuss the potential hazards however don't give a definitive verdict as to whether the BMS would be advisable for small wearables specifically.

Given the experience on this forum, would these extra protections be necessary/advisable in an internationally distributed small wearable product or would they be unnecessary? In other words, is a BMS necessary with a 3.7V battery or are they are primarily designed and aimed at things like cordless drills which are usually 18V+?

Kind Regards,
Andy

Comment: Would you buy a product and wear it, where the safety standards were debatable? Are you asking us for permission to put your clients at risk? Are you asking for us to tell you to design it according to your conscience? Are you asking us whether if your conscience and your financial models don't align, which one you should follow? Voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: Finance is not a factor here. Safety is the aim of the game and that is what I'm trying to learn. The purpose of the question is to find out if a BMS is necessary with a 3.7V battery or if they are primarily designed and aimed at things like cordless drills which are usually 18V+.

Comment: Of course finance is an issue here, if your conscience and financials aligned, then you wouldn't be asking the question, duh!

Comment: My knowledge of designing circuits is limited, please assist me in learning more Neil. Is a BMS useful in every circuit design no matter the battery voltage or is implementing a BMS for a wearable like driving a 300km/h car in a 60km/h zone - overkill and unnecessary?

Comment: Usually single cell consumer devices use a battery protection circuit, not usually called a BMS. It is partly a terminology thing, I guess. Although with a single cell, there is no balancing, for example. So a BMS may have to deal with balancing, but a protection circuit doesn't. Usually the protection circuit is integral with the battery itself. Seiko seems to be the industry leader in battery protection circuits.  http://www.sii-ic.com/en/semicon/products/power-management-ic/lithium-ion-battery-protection-ic/

Comment: Overcharging leads to a fire risk, does your charger IC prevent overcharging under all likely scenarios? Undrvoltage only kills your battery, single cell means no balancing is required.

Comment: Batteries in wearables should have a protection circuit. The protection circuit should include a fuse, just in case the electronics fail. See my seiko link in previous comment.

Comment: Thanks Neil and mkeith. The charging IC we're using has 
20-V Maximum Input Voltage Tolerance, with input overvoltage Protection, (ii) Thermal Shutdown and Overcurrent Protection, and (iii)  Temperature Monitoring and Fault Detection. Source: www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq51050b.pdf page 1 left column.

Comment: Every lithium pouch cell I have ever seen had a protection circuit built-in to it. Sizes I have dealt with range from around 100 mAh to around 4 Ah. Every single one had a seiko protection circuit in it. This is how we bought them. I am sure the suppliers would provide samples without a protection circuit if you asked, but they certainly are familiar with protection circuits. You want to make sure no single failure can lead to overcharge of the battery. The charger IC is a single point of failure. Note that multiple failures which result from a single cause are considered single failures.

Comment: My point being, in case it wasn't clear, that you can probably get your battery pack from the supplier with a protection circuit on it already. You shouldn't have to design it yourself or put it on your circuit board. It is part of the pack. That is typical in industry.

Comment: Perfect, so we should ensure our battery manufacturer provides protection circuitry with the battery itself, then from our end ensure the charger we utilise (like the BQ51050b listed above) also includes protection circuitry?

Comment: The BQ51050b is a charger IC. That is what it would typically be called. It does have safety features, but it is not considered a protection IC. You definitely need a charger IC, and my experience with TI single cell chargers has generally been positive. Never used that specific one. So yeah, you need both.

Comment: Sorry mkeith, when you say 'need both' - do you mean the BQ51050b (as the charger IC) AND a separate IC (like the http://au.mouser.com/Search/Refine.aspx?Keyword=AP9211SA) as the protection IC? Or are the safety features on that IC sufficient?

Comment: You need a charger IC (like the BQ51050b) on your device. And the battery pack needs to have (or typically has) a protection IC, such as one of the seiko ones I mentioned earlier. The two IC's perform different functions. The charger IC charges the battery. If it should fail in such a way that the battery is charged too fast or to too high a voltage, the protection circuit will open up and prevent further charging. The protection circuit is typically a very small PCB built into the battery.

Comment: Thanks a lot mkeith, if you want to post one of these as an answer I'll select it as the solution so you can receive the points. By the way, if you have any particular recommendations for battery suppliers - feel free to let me know at andystanton88@gmail.com

Comment: When you say a "wearable device" what do you mean exactly? Is it simply a device embedded in a piece of garment, or it is directly in touch with the human body, as you seem to imply when you talk about an heart rate monitor....

Comment: ...In this latter case I would add redundant protection circuitry (note that this may also be required by legislation). Moreover, e.g., what could happen if, by misfortune, the wearer falls on rocky terrain during a mountain trip. Could a bad fall, possibly heavily damaging the piece of garment, lead to multiple failures in your system that could put the life or the health of the wearer at risk?

Comment: Before you design your circuit, you should assess the potential risks derived from the actual environments in which your piece of garment could be possibly used. If you didn't do that, you couldn't possibly do a sensible design.

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo, it will be embedded in a piece of fabric then against the users body. It will be going through the washing machine so the heavy impact you mention is relevant. We're using a very solid hard plastic enclosure which does not break in the machine. Lorenzo do you recommend more than the methods already described in these comments?

Comment: Washing machine? You probably should have mentioned that earlier. I have never designed anything that had to go through a washing machine. It sounds very challenging. You better find someone who has done it before and work with him/her.

Comment: 90 degree C wash cycle should kill most batteries.

Comment: To the OP: can you find one single product with a lithium battery which is advertised as being able to be run through a washing machine?

Comment: I've noticed this one has been advertised to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcmKXd3miuA

Comment: Also there are numerous videos on youtube of the GoPro Hero3 going through the washing machine

Comment: Pretty impressive. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is needed will depend on how your device is marketed: in which countries you will sell it, will it be a certified medical device or not, etc. Specific requirements will apply in each case and it's too broad for an answer.

Also, most standards don't ask you to implement a particular feature such as BMS but to satisfy specific requirements. A good start would be the norm IEC 62133, which defines specific tests your battery should pass (mechanical damage, over-current, overcharge etc.). AFAIK this norm is used a lot for wearable batteries, but it might be insufficient or overly strict depending on what device you have exactly, as explained above.

AFAIK a simple wearable gadget with no medical functionality will be OK with a simple fuse for over-current protection. Some medical devices also get away with very simple chargers if the user is unable to charge the battery while wearing/using the device (e.g. electrical toothbrushes).

Answer (score 0):

There are too many documented cases of batteries causing fires. You need to make sure that protection is included, especialy as the person wearing it may not be able to remove it quickly unlike a phone which can be thrown away.